# In flutter, for how long does the fcm token persist?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Specifically I wonder what events would change a device's fcm token? Forcibly closing the app doesn't seem to do it, though I have read somewhere that the token might change. Would it change for a user who uninstalls the app and then reinstalls it?

I would like to reliably send a push notification to a device - without risking the fcm token being changed - as long as the user doesn't intentionally change their token by themselves.

I've spent many hours trying to understand firebase and firebase cloud messaging. To be honest I find the documentation very disappointing, and I'm wondering how to be able to write reliable apps using firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should expect that the FCM token may change for reasons outside of your control.  Flutter is not different than the underlying native system in this respect.  The possible reasons that a token may change are not documented, but your app should be ready to deal with a new token at any time, using the APIs provided.